# Override Eloquent Query Builder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, query-builder

I'm trying to override Eloquent's Query Builder.

I have tried the following for my `MyModel`:

```
<?php

class CustomQueryBuilder extends Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder
{
    public function get($columns = array('*'))
    {
        die('get');
    }
}

use CustomQueryBuilder as Builder;
class MyModel extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
{
    // the model that needs the custom query builder
}
```

But when I run `MyModel::get()` it still returns the object instead of dying.

Any ideas how to make this work?

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but at a minimum, you'll need to implement (and override) [`Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::newBaseQueryBuilder`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php) in your model to have it use your new Builder class.

```
/**
 * Get a new query builder instance for the connection.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder
 */
protected function newBaseQueryBuilder()
{
    $conn = $this->getConnection();
    $grammar = $conn->getQueryGrammar();
    return new CustomQueryBuilder($conn, $grammar, $conn->getPostProcessor());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to do it is :

```
<?php

namespace MyNamespace\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder as BaseBuilder;
use \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Builder extends BaseBuilder
{
   public function like($key, $value){
       return $this->orWhere($key, 'like', '%' . $value . '%');
   }
}  


class MyModel extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'mytable';

    public function newEloquentBuilder($query)
    {
       return new Builder($query);
    }
}
```